# Генерация цветов php

Tags: алгоритм, php

Какой алгоритм посоветуете для генерации html цветов, чтобы они были приятны глазу и значительно отличались (можно отличить друг от друга)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На вкус и цвет, как говорится... Может сюда посмотреть: [20 Color Scheme Generators for Web and Graphic Designers](http://www.youthedesigner.com/2011/04/05/20-color-scheme-generators-for-web-and-graphic-designers/)

Comment: ну в общем пришел к выводу, что лучше заранее сгенерить цвета руками. Хорошего алгоритма не нашел :) Спасибо за ссылочку )